# Create a backup Copy of a file every 5 minutes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, backup

There is a game that uses one save file. That save file is written to every couple of seconds. I want a skript to create a backup copy of that save file every 5 minutes. The output should look like this:

`c:\users\...\10000.sl2` <-- Original

`C:\users\...\backup\10000-15.02.2019_18-34.sl2`

`C:\users\...\backup\10000-15.02.2019_18-39.sl2`

I tried to put something together using LastWriteTime

```
PS C:\Users\...> $source = "C:\Users\...76561198109841889"
>> $destination = "C:\Users\...76561198109841889\backups"
>>
>> Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Include *.sl2 | % {
>>     $name = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".sl2"
>>     #$name = "Finished_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".sl2"
>>     #$name = "Finished_" + $_.Name.Split(".")[0] +  "_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.LastWriteTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".sl2"
>>     Rename-Item $_ -NewName $name
>>     Copy-Item "$($_.Directory)\$name" -Destination $destination
```

I found this code by googling my question. Hitting Enter produces a bunch of files but then nothing happens again.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use so much pipeline as it is hard to debug. Consider for loops, Start-Sleep, not using Rename-Item to make a copy of the file, verify the file is not locked by the game for exclusive access, possibly naming files such that they sort naturally. Happy to help (as others are), but SO is not a code writing service. No disrespect meant, but all you've done here is post code you found elsewhere that it seems you do not understand.

Comment: ok. I understand. So I have found this code to a very similar question to mine, that is why I thought I could manipulate it to my needs without adequate knowledge of PowerShell. I researched a little further and found  `FileSystemWatcher` Maybe that could do what I'm looking for. Another solution I found online was to create a batch file and have windows task scheduler execute it every 5 minutes. But that seems awkward. My interest in finding a solution to that problem is very high, so much so that I'm willing to learn what is necessary in PowerShell. Just a couple more tips would be very nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this game is writing one file and only one file. Meaning replacing it every few seconds, then looking at that time stamp is meaningless, as it would never hit a different time span.

Just set a scheduled to copy the file every 5 mins. It does not matter If you use PowerShell or Batch file to do it. When you copy, of course give it a new name in the destination.

```
$TimeStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('mmddyyyhhmmss')
Copy-Item -Path 'D:\Game\GameFileName' -Destination "D:\Game\Backup\$(GameFileName)_$(TimeStamp).bak"
```